# google cloud Stackdriver Metrics to scale an Manage instance group - Regional

Tags: google-compute-engine, google, autoscaling, gcloud, google-stackdriver

What are the Stackdriver Metrics we can use to autoscale Regional Manage instance groups ?
When i check the docs it says
Regional managed instance groups do not support filtering for per-instance metrics.
Regional managed instance groups do not support autoscaling using per-group metrics.

Is that mean I can not use any Stackdriver Metrics other than CPU ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported for regional or multi-zones autoscaling. There is no workaround for this scenario, only as a [recommendation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-stackdriver-monitoring-metrics#filter_per_group_metrics), you can try to use a metric should be enough specific to return one single time series since otherwise the metric could not be assimilated to trigger the autoscaling.

Product team has been notified about this limitation, and a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/146521009) currently exists related to however there is no ETA yet of when this will be available for regional manage instance groups. Feel free to post there should you have any additional comments or concerns regarding the issue.

Comment: got the same from google yesterday but love to add their comment here with.

 You can only use per-instance metrics to scale a Regional MIG. If you need to scale based on a metric which is a per-group metric then you will have to use Zonal MIG. Note: You cannot use filters in the per-instance metrics. You won't be able to scale correctly if a metric reports values for multiple states for the metric being observed

Comment: Yes we have some limitation : 1- You cannot autoscale based on Cloud Monitoring logs-based metrics.2-Regional managed instance groups do not support filtering for per-instance metrics.3-Regional managed instance groups do not support autoscaling using per-group metrics. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-stackdriver-monitoring-metrics#limitations